# Reasons for using svelte js

Tags: reactjs, web, vue.js, svelte

I found the Svelte framework these days. What do you think about using it instead of React.js or Vue.js?

I didn't use it at all so I don't understand the deep difference between them. I have read that Svelte much faster, but it doesn't have certain support for state storing like redux and so on. So what can you say about this?
I tried to find some more info about the advantages and disadvantages but it was in vain.

Comment: This statement isn't true *"rather than interpreting your application code at run time, your app is converted into ideal JavaScript at build time"*, this is exactly what vue's [single file components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) are

Comment: @craig_h I'm afraid you're entirely wrong. Vue's SFCs can be compiled to an *intermediate representation*, which still needs Vue itself in order to do any work. It reduces *some* client-side work (no need to parse the template), but that's all. Svelte's components, by contrast, are converted into raw code. They're completely different ideas.

Comment: @RichHarris Thanks for clarifying that point, I hadn't considered that but it is a crucial difference, sorry if that came across a bit judgy I hadn't had my morning cup of tea! Anyway, it looks like a great project. Good luck with it :)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Svelte is a different take on the idea of building UIs. Rather than being a library that runs in the browser to create your UI, it's a compiler that turns your component into simple JavaScript, with no need for virtual DOM diffing or any of the other techniques that UI libraries use.

The resulting code is faster, but it's also smaller, more portable, and — crucially, especially on mobile — has lower memory requirements.

You absolutely *can* use Redux or any other state management system with Svelte. But it has built-in state management that's powerful enough that you probably won't need it.

Comment: Thank you for reply! I will try to create a project and test it))

Comment: @Rich Harris Do you know of any slightly complicated site built with Svetle already ?

Comment: @MariánZekeŠedaj not off the top of my head — you could ask around in https://gitter.im/sveltejs/svelte

Comment: Fast-forward to 2021, the official website of [Radio France](https://www.radiofrance.com/) is being redone in Svelte. Here's the [Beta](https://beta.radiofrance.fr/) version in Svelte which is still a WIP as of today.